# Automatically Mark risky file-local-variable safe?

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables, encryption

I'm using org-crypt, and I wanted to automatically disable autosave for that particular buffer. Following the [suggestion in the documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Crypt.html), I put the following line at the top of my org file:

```
# -*- buffer-auto-save-file-name: nil; -*-
```

And it works. But now I'm being prompted to confirm that I want to apply the local variable, with a warning that the [local variable is risky](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html).

Is there any way I can "advise" or "override" this for this particular variable (preferably for just this file)?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure it out, but you can mark particular values for a variable as safe.

You can set the option using the handy menu (Options->Customize Emacs->Specific-Option and search for `safe-local-variable-values`) and use the handy dialog to do it.

Or you can add something like this to your emacs initialization file:

```
(add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values
             'buffer-auto-safe-file-name))
```

Comment: ... or you can answer `!` when it prompts you.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that and it told me "wrong answer"

Comment: It's always worked for me - try again perhaps?